# How to make a div clickable and redirect to an url Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

This might seem like a stupid question but I am learning Angular JS these days and came across a problem. I want to make a div clickable and once you click on it, it should go to another page, but I can't seem to make it work....

```html
<div class="test" ng-click="{{ '/url?language=' + $control.lang }}"></div>
```

Comment: `ng-click` will work if you want to use a function and then the `$location` service to do the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `[ng-href][1]` directive is for. Compiled acts as a simple html `href` attribute.

```
<a class="test" ng-href="/url?language={{$control.lang}}"></a>
```

If you wanted to use `[ng-click][1]` because of some reason, you would actually need to call a function from within your controller. Inside the function you'd have to manually change the location using `[$location][1]` or `$window` module preferably.

```
$scope.GoTo = function(url){
   $location.path(url); 
}
```

Then your div would become

```
<div class="test" ng-click="GoTo('/url?language='+$control.lang)"></div>
```

Make sure you inject the `$location` module into your controller too.

Comment: This does not work on a div and I need the element to be a div

Comment: @coffeeak Of course it doesn't. Divs do not have href attributes. Take a look at my edit showing how to get it working with a div.